# Why my laptop is crashing after installing Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lenovo, crash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing ubuntu 20.04 on my windows device Lenovo IdeaPad 320 I face multiple problems like hangs and system crashing.

It works normally but suddenly it hangs and I have to restart the computer. Sometimes during boot, it shows up some weird message.

One thing to note, it does not appear every time. Also sometimes it gets worse and when I try to restart it start noising.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this problem? Why Ubuntu is not compatible with my device?

Comment: Did you ever get your laptop to stop crashing? I have a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad E15 and dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Both occasionally crash (randomly restart). Also, the external USB-C monitor frequently flickers to black on Ubuntu. I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04  is still  unstable.

Im recomend  to go into boot options.

And switch  to other mode if errors  is with  drivers  try:

quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu

Choose recovery mode.

Select a menu option and press Enter to use it:

```
clean: Attempts to make free space on your file system. If your storage is full and this is causing some sort of problem, this can help free up space.
dpkg: Repairs broken software packages. If a package failed to install properly and your system doesn’t work because of it, this may help.
failsafeX: Boots your computer in a failsafe graphic mode. If there’s a problem with your Xorg graphical server configuration or graphics drivers and that’s causing your Ubuntu system to boot to a black screen or preventing the graphical desktop from loading properly, this can get you back to that graphical desktop.
fsck: Performs a file system check, which scans the computer’s file systems for errors and automatically fixes them. It’s a bit like chkdsk on Windows.
grub: Updates the GRUB boot loader. If you could use the GRUB boot loader to get to this menu, this option probably won’t help.
network: Enable networking, which is disabled by default in recovery mode.
root: Leaves the menu and goes to a root shell prompt. From here, you can mount the file system in write-mode and run commands that may help fix problems with the system. You should only do this if you know what you’re doing — it’s a way to fix the problem by hand if you know how.
```

[image]