# Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot crashing, wondering if fix is available

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, crash

I've seen quite a few problems on here that are nearly identical to my own. My laptop runs dual boot Windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 and is running on AMD Ryzen 7 4800H Processor, 16 GB memory, and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti 4GB graphics. The model is the Lenovo Legion 5 15.

I've seen some reviews specifically for this laptop that said other people had issues running ubuntu, but nothing exceptionally terrible; some claimed touchpad didn't work, but it's fine on mine-- I bought a mouse anyways. For the most part, it's been alright, except for crashes frequent enough to be worried.

Some other questions I've read regarding crashing said stuttering audio before unresponsiveness which I've noticed. I've tried to make it crash on Windows without success so I'm fairly sure (fingers crossed) it's not a hardware issue. It seems to happen most when running Blender/other digital drawing applications, or when running Spotify. I also don't have the option to run a memory test in my grub menu.  In any case, have these been worked out within the past week and a bit? I haven't seen any answers yet (I might not be looking in the right places). I've heard other people had returned to 18.04 so I might do that in the meantime, but am hoping for a fix!

Thanks in advance for any help x

Comment: Your question should include /var/log/syslog around the time of a crash. If there are .crash files in /var/crash, a directory listing showing the full names of those files would also be helpful in your question.

Comment: Did you ever get your laptop to stop crashing? I have a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad E15 and dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Both occasionally crash (randomly restart). Also, the external USB-C monitor frequently flickers to black on Ubuntu. I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks. P.S. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/1273498/48214